# Assistance: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class fragment

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments

When trying to add a header and footer view to my postListFragment I get the inflating error Binary XML #11

im not sure im inflating my header and footer correctly. Its the postListFragment is my List view

I also have a refreshableListView class should I inflate the header view there instead? Any help is appreciated

```
public PostListFragment() {
    //default url
    this.rssURL = GlobalClass.RSSURL;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_postlist, container, false);


    View lheader = inflater.inflate(R.layout.header, null);
    View lfooter = inflater.inflate(R.layout.footer, null);
    postListView.addHeaderView(lheader);
    postListView.addFooterView(lfooter);
    postListView = (RefreshableGridView) 
          rootView.findViewById(R.id.postListView);
    postAdapter = new PostItemAdapter(this.getActivity(), R.layout.postitem,        

 PostDataModel.getInstance().listData);
    postListView.setAdapter(postAdapter);
    postListView.setOnRefresh(this);
    postListView.setOnItemClickListener(onItemClickListener);
    PostDataModel.getInstance().setDelegate(this);
    return rootView;
```

Manifest:

```
 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.dgcom.rssreader.SplashActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/postlistlabel" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Here is my header

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TextView
android:id="@+id/header"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:background="#cf9f99"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my postlistview

```
<!-- activity_postlist.xml -->
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#000000">

<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/adsContainer"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


<ListView
    android:id="@+id/postListView"

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:columnWidth="300dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:horizontalSpacing="40dp"
    android:verticalSpacing="200dp"
    android:numColumns="2"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

fragment_postlist

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/adsContainer"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<com.dgcom.rssreader.component.RefreshableGridView
    android:id="@+id/postListView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:dividerHeight="100dp"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:divider="#b0b0b0"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:fadingEdge="none"
    android:numColumns="2"
    android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

footer layout

Comment: I think the postListView and postitem layout xmls are more interesting than the manifest

Comment: can you add the others too? fragment_postlist, header, footer

Comment: Is your `PostListFragment` listed in the `Activity`'s layout file, in a `<fragment>` element? If so, I believe your problem is that you're getting a `NullPointerException` in `onCreateView()` because you're not initializing `postListView`, which is causing the `Activity`'s layout inflation to fail, thus your `InflateException`.

Comment: I took out the following code from my postlistfragment class              `View lheader = inflater.inflate(R.layout.header, null);
        View lfooter = inflater.inflate(R.layout.footer, null);
postListView.addHeaderView(lheader);
        postListView.addFooterView(lfooter);`                                            and my application ran, I think i need to reformat that code

Comment: You just need to move the `postListView = (RefreshableGridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.postListView);` line to right after the `View rootView = ...` line. I don't notice before that you just had the initialization in the wrong place.

Comment: @MikeM., you're right, but strange, I would expect to see the usual NullPointerException because of that. So I think the InflateException must come ('cause of course we don't know what line exactly caused it) from one of the "inflate" lines.

Comment: @Gavriel It's coming from the the `Activity`'s `setContentView()` method, which has an `inflate()` call in it. It's just such a deep stack trace that it gets truncated.

Comment: @MikeM. l thanks for your help moving the lines of code worked I appreciate it!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to move the postListView = (RefreshableGridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.postListView); line to right after the View rootView = ... line. I don't notice before that you just had the initialization in the wrong place. – Mike M. 19 hours ago